# Cannot read json response properties in angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, callback, controller

I am using Angular.js controller named 'forecastController'.

Angular.js Controller code is:

```
weatherApp.controller('forecastController', 
    ['$scope','$routeParams','cityService', 'weatherService', function($scope, $routeParams , cityService, weatherService)
{    
    $scope.city=cityService.city;
    $scope.days=$routeParams.days || '2' ;
    $scope.weatherResult=weatherService.GetWeather($scope.city, $scope.days); //I get valid json response, the format is mentioned down below.
    console.log($scope.weatherResult.city.name); //Not working, this is the problem
}]);
```

Json object '$scope.weatherResult' is:

```
{
  "city":     
  {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": {
      "lon": -0.12574,
      "lat": 51.50853
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 0
  },
  "cod": "200"
}
```

My service is

```
weatherApp.service('weatherService', ['$resource',function($resource){
    this.GetWeather=function(city, days){

        var weatherAPI=$resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID={{MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE}}",{
        callback:"JSON_CALLBACK"}, {get:{method:"JSONP"}});

        return weatherAPI.get({q:city, cnt:days});     
    };
}]);
```

My 'forecastController' receives valid $scope.weatherResult. And in the HTML view I can access weatherResult json object properties. I have ensured it properly. For an example, {{weatherResult.city.name}} works. But, if I try to print in console.log inside my 'forecaseController' I get value undefined. The json data I am getting is from http://openweathermap.org/api

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:50926/controllers.js:19:42)
    at e (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:36:215)
    at Object.instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:36:344)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:72:460
    at link (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js:7:268)
    at Fc (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:68:47)
    at K (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:57:259)
    at g (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:49:491)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:49:99
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:50:474 <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service `weatherService.GetWeather` likely returns a promise. Until that promise is resolved, the properties in your `$scope.weatherResult` object will be undefined. Use the promise `then` method:

```
$scope.weatherResult = weatherService.GetWeather($scope.city, $scope.days);
$scope.weatherResult.$promise.then(function() {
    console.log($scope.weatherResult.city.name);
});
```

**Update**: As per my comment, the service is returning a `$resource` object. This object has a `$promise` property.

**[Link To Codepen](http://codepen.io/caroach1080/pen/vLprba)**

Comment: Hi Corey, I tried your suggestion, It is not working. I have added the service code if you can have a look and suggest me something else, too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's returning a `$resource` object which has a `$promise` property. I've updated the answer to include the `$promise.then` method. It's untested...

Comment: I tried as per your 2nd solution. Still not working. Same error.

Comment: Noticed my mistake and broke it out into two lines. Also, added a link with a working example.